# When to use stdint.h's scalars in driver code

Tags: c, linux, driver

It has come to my attention that there seems no consistency nor best practise when to use native scalar types (integer, short, char) or the ones provided by stdint: uint32_t uint16_t uint8_t.

This is bugging me a lot because drivers form an essential part of a kernel that needs to be maintainable, consistent, stable and good.

Here is an illustrational example in gcc (used this for a hobby project for the raspberry pi):

```
// using native scalars
struct fbinfo {
        unsigned width, height;
        unsigned vwidth, vheight;
        unsigned pitch, bits;
        int x, y;
        void *ptr;
        unsigned size;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));

// using stdint scalars
struct fbinfo {
        uint32_t width, height;
        uint32_t vwidth, vheight;
        uint32_t pitch, bits;
        int32_t x, y;
        uint32_t ptr; // convert to void* in order to use it
        uint32_t size;
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

To me, the first example seems more logical, because this piece of code
is only intended to run on a raspberry pi. It would be pointless to run
this on other hardware.

The second example seems more practical, because it looks more
descriptive since C does not guarantee much about the size of integers. 
It may be 16 bits or something else. uint32_t, uint_fast32_t and variants make guarantees about the exact or approximated size: e.g. at least or at most X bytes.

The operating system development community tends to use the stdint types, while the linux kernel uses multiple different techniques: u32, __u32, and endian specific stuff like __le32.

What considerations should be taken into account when to choose a scalar type and when to use a typedef'd scalar type? Is it better to use native scalar types in the provided example or use stdint.h's?

Comment: I think it's a matter of the application itself. When the width of a data type is actually changing the semantic behavior of the program (when performing some bit-specific operations or writing toa hardware registers), it makes sense to use the `stdint` types. When doing some abstract math, it's better to use the built-in types, as the behavior is well defined for them regardless of platform.

Comment: Another aspect is self-documenting code. What's the actual problem using fixed width types? If it's just the typing, use an editor with auto-completion. Re. portability, you might want to read the early posting of Linus Torvalds, and what he wrote about porting Linux to other archs (resp. not porting).

Comment: @eugene, that's a really good point that it depends on the application and if it would change the semantic behavior of the program.@olaf IMO, it's for clarity and consistency. Unfortunately, I could not find a response by Linus in a thread regarding that topic. I did find [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg75564.html) thread which discusses the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. fixed with vs. fundamental types

Fixed width types are sometimes difficultly to use. E.g. `printf()` specifiers for `int32_t` are `PRIi32` and require splitting of the format string:

```
printk("foo=" PRIi32 ", bar=" PRIi32 "\n", foo, bar);
```

Fixed width types should/must be used when hardware is accessed directly; e.g. when writing DMA descriptors.  But for simple register accesses, `writel()` or `readl()` functions can be used which work with fundamental types.

As a rule of thumb, when a certain memory layout is assumed (like the `__attribute__((__aligned__(16)))` in your example, fixed width types should be used.

Signed fixed width types (`int32_t x,y` in your example) might need double checking, whether their representation matches the hardware expectations.

**NOTE** that in your example, the second structure is architecture dependent because of

```
    uint32_t ptr; // convert to void* in order to use it
```

Writing such thing in common C would be `uintptr_t ptr` and in the kernel it is common to write

```
    unsigned long ptr;
```

Alternatively, `dma_addr_t` might be a better type.

## 2. `uint32_t` vs. `__u32`

More than 10 years ago, Linus Torvalds objected against `uint32_t` because at this time, non-C99 compilers were common and using such types in (exported) linux headers would pollute the namespace.

But now, `uint32_t` and similar types are available everywhere (you can not compile the kernel with a non-C99 compiler) and kernel header export has been improved significantly, so these arguments are gone.

It is a matter of personal preference whether to use standard types or typedef'ed variants (which are framework dependent and differ between them).

## 3. `uint_fastX_t` and variants

They are not used in the kernel and I would avoid them.  They combine disadvantages of `uint32_t` (difficult usage) and `int` (variable width).

## 4. `__le32` vs. `__u32`

Use the endian types when specification explicitly requires them (e.g. in network protocol implementations).  This makes it easy to detect wrong usage (e.g. assignments like `endian_variable = native_variable`).

Do not use them e.g. for filling processor structures (e.g. DMA descriptors); some processors can run both in little and big endian mode and native datatypes are usually the right way to write such infomration.

Comment: I guess there is no definite way to determine which type is best, but using these `guidelines' it makes the choice a lot easier.